# No gedit Text Size Plugin in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gedit, plugins

In Ubuntu 16.04, I could open Gedit and go Preferences -> Plugins and then check the box for the Text-Size plugin, but that Plugin no longer appears in the list for the version that runs in Ubuntu 18.04. Please advise.

Comment: What is the goal? Want to change the font size in editor?

Comment: @cmak.fr yes, using the mouse scroll

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `gedit` plugins should be installed

Find available plugins:

```
apt-cache search gedit-plugin-*
```

Install the text-size plugin:

```
sudo apt install gedit-plugin-text-size
```

Comment: In my situation (Ubuntu 18.04, gedit 3.28.1) the installation terminates successfully but I do not see the plugin showing up within gedit. If I look in /usr/share/gedit/plugins/externaltools/tools, where the previous plug-ins are located, I cannot see this new one.

Comment: @XavierStuvw get list of installed files with `dpkg -L gedit-plugin-text-size` - See the Plugins area in Gedit Preferences